What is causing my Mac Studio window server and entire system crash every day all year with 8K screen?
I've been having same the crash on my Mac Studio numerous times every day since first installing macOS Sonoma about a month after it was first released last fall.
I'm using a Samsung NEO QLED 8K TV as the monitor.
It often happens right when I'm in the middle of a data backup or upload after I walk away from the computer. It never happens when I am actually typing on the computer or moving the mouse, but randomly anytime after that. Sometimes a minute after I walk away. Sometimes an hour. I have tried all sleep and power settings, screensavers, etc.
At first I expected Apple to fix it in the point release, because I have clicked report every time, but it's never been fixed.
I've used the same monitor since the beginning of August 2023, and never had this crash for several months until the first day I installed macOS Sonoma, and have had it every day since then when my computer has been used more than a trivial amount.
Is anyone else seeing this?
Apple is not doing anything about it even though I have reported it every day to them with the automatic Report button.
It's obviously not caused by the monitor since the same monitor never caused the crash anytime until the day I installed Sonoma.
But it could be related to the monitor, like a windows server bug when trying to drive 8K to the screen. It only happens while I'm not typing or moving the mouse, though.
SAMSUNG:
  Resolution:   7680 x 4320 (4320p/8K UHD 2 - 8K Ultra High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    3840 x 2160 @ 60.00Hz
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  No
  Television:   Yes

Mac Studio
2023
Chip Apple M2 Max
Memory
32 GB
Startup disk
Macintosh HD
Serial number
G4...
macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
More Info..
Regulatory Certification
TM and © 1983-2024 Apple Inc.

Your computer was restarted because of a problem.
This report will be sent automatically to Apple.
› Comments
Problem Details and System Configuration
panic(cpu 3 caller Oxfffffe00271922dc): Kernel data abort. at pc Oxfffffe0027eaa414, 1r 0xa5917e0027eaa40c (saved state:
Oxfffffe73cf1bb360)
0x0000000000000027 ×1:
0х0000000000000000
Oxfffffe00253cfdd0 x5:
0X0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 ×9:
Oxfffffe29c865720
х12: 0x0000020000000000 x13:
0x0000000000000000
x16: 0xfffffe00269a4e40 x17:
0x000000000000ae56
x20: 0xfffffe202ed46000 x21:
0X0000000000000000
x24: 0xfffffe24f3b0cc0 x25:
0x0000000000000000
x28: 0xfffffe002a117000 fp:
Oxfffffe73cf1bb730
Oxfffffe0027eaa414 cpsr: 0x60401208 x2:
0х0000000000000000
х6:
0X0000000000000000
x10: 0x0000000000000002 x14:
0x0000000000000000
х18:
0x0000000000000000 x22:
0x0000000000000001
х26: 0x0000000000000000
1r:
0xa5917e0027eaa40c
esr: 0x96000006
x3:
00000000000000
X7 :
0x00000000ca6e000e
x11: 0x0000000000000000
x15: 0x0000000000000010
x19: 0x0000000000000000
х23: 0x0000000000000000
x27: 0xfffffe202ed48540
sp:
Oxfffffe73cf1bb6b0
far: 0x00000000000001ec
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: Oxff
OS release type: User
OS version: 23G93
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.6.0: Mon Jul 29 21:13:04 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.141.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_6020
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: C58433CAF051B51A1E8941427B6C3CF3
Kernel UUID: 5CDB68A-1888-3A5C-92B3-86C864439A24
Boot session UUID: 699FAEBD-1CF2-4365-8499-6243F3EC91EF
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.140.19
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000013a8000
KernelCache base:
Oxfffffe00253ac000
Kernel slide:
0x000000001€360000
Kernel text base:
Oxfffffe00253b4000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x000000001f924000
Kernel text
exec base:
Oxfffffe0026928000
mach
_absolute_time: 0x43eaa3d8e73
Epoch
Time:
sec
usec
Boot
: 0x66c1ca7
0x000568a4
Sleep
0x00000000
0x00000000
Wake
0x00000000
0x00000000
Calendar:
0x66d01443
0x00091cbf
Zone info:
Zone map:
Oxfffffe102ea10000 - 0xfffffe302ea10000
• VM
Oxfffffe102a10000 - 0xfffffe14fb6d000
• RO
Oxfffffe14fb6d000 - 0xfffffe1695074000
GENO
: Oxfffffe1695074000 - 0xfffffe1b61d40000
• GEN1
Oxfffffelb61d40000
- Oxfffffe202ea0c000
• GEN2
: Oxfffffe202ea0c000
Oxfffffe24fb6d8000
• GEN3
: Oxfffffe24fb6d8000
- Oxfffffe29c83a4000


Problem Report for macOS
Your computer was restarted because of a problem.
This report will be sent automatically to Apple.
› Comments
Problem Details and System Configuration
• GENS DATA
: Oxfffffe29c83a4000 - 0xfffffe302ea10000
Metadata:
Oxfffffe10004b0000 - 0xfffffe10084b0000
Bitmaps: Oxfffffe10084b0000 - 0xfffffe100200000
Extra
: 0 - 0
TPIDRX_ELy = {1: 0xfffffe202d399fa0
0: 0x0000000000000003
Oro: 0x00000001616300 }
CORE
PVH locks held: None
CORE
1
PVH
locks held:
None
CORE
2 PVH
locks held: None
CORE
3
PVHI
locks
held: None
CORE
4
PVH
locks
held: None
CORE
5 PVH locks held: None
CORE
6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE
8 PVH locks held: None
CORE 9 PVH locks held: None
CORE 10 PVH locks held: None
CORE 11 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0: PC=0x0000000185c16b28, LR=0x0000000185ac82ec, FP=0x000000016cf260
CORE
1: PC=0x000000018e1fc3dc, LR=0x000000018df6ede4,
FP=0x000000016e94efa0
CORE CORE
2: PC=0x0000000185c50594, LR=0x000000018e0cdf5c,
FP=0x000000016f541a90
3 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE
4: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de8, LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4, FP=0xfffffe73cecd7ef0
CORE CORE
5: PC=0x0000000185a684a0, LR=0x0000000185a67d70, FP=0x000000016f3b1a80
6: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de8, LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4, FP=0xfffffe73cd0bfef0
CORE
7: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de8, LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4, FP=0xfffffe73cebdbef0
CORE 8: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de8, LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4, FP=0xfffffe73cebcfef0
CORE 9: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de4, LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4, FP=0xfffffe73ce8d7ef0
CORE 10: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de4, LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4, FP=0xfffffe73cf1f7ef0
CORE 11: PC=0xfffffe00269b9de8,
LR=0xfffffe00269b9de4,
FP=0xfffffe73cf2dbef0
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 2 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xfffffe1b64d357d8: 11744 pages, 24 threads: pid 152: WindowServer Panicked thread: 0xfffffe202d399a0, backtrace: Oxfffffe73cf1baad0, tid: 3114
1r: 0xfffffe002697f48c
fp: Oxfffffe73cf1bab60
1r: Oxfffffe0026accabc
fp: 0xfffffe73cf1babd0
Ir: Oxfffffe0026acae88
p: Oxfffffe73cf1baca0
Ir: Oxfffffe002692f8cc
fp: 0xfffffe73cf1bacb0
Ir: Oxfffffe002697ed80
fp: 0xfffffe73cf1bb060
1r:
Oxfffffe0027187248
fp: Oxfffffe73cf1bb080
Ir:
Oxfffffe00271922dc fp:
1r:
Oxfffffe0026acc8d4
Oxfffffe73cf1bb200
fp:
Ir:
Oxfffffe0026acb028
fp:
Oxfffffe73cf1bb270
1r:
Oxfffffe002692f8cc
Oxfffffe73cf1bb340
fp:
1r:
Oxfffffe0027eaa40c
Oxfffffe73cf1bb350
fp:
Oxfffffe73cf1bb730
a:hhhhh：ラランカトレラクタ
Hide Details
OK

The important line above may be the line mentioning the window server:
Panicked task 0xfffffe1b64d357d8: 11744 pages, 24 threads: pid 152: WindowServer Panicked thread: 0xfffffe202d399a0, backtrace: Oxfffffe73cf1baad0, tid: 3114
This is another more complete and readable copy of the most recent crash report out of thousands, this one from a few minutes ago today:
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe002e3f22dc): Kernel data abort. at pc 0xfffffe002f10a414, lr 0x42f57e002f10a40c (saved state: 0xfffffe83e1697360)
      x0:  0x0000000000000027 x1:  0x0000000000000000  x2:  0x0000000000000000  x3:  0x0000000000000000
      x4:  0xfffffe002c62fdd0 x5:  0x0000000000000000  x6:  0x0000000000000000  x7:  0x00000000000d000c
      x8:  0x0000000000000000 x9:  0xfffffe31a8a8d130  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000000
      x12: 0x0000020000000000 x13: 0x0000000000004000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000010
      x16: 0xfffffe002dc04e40 x17: 0x000000000000ae56  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
      x20: 0xfffffe2cdbabf000 x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x0000000000000000
      x24: 0xfffffe280f9de5c0 x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0xfffffe2cdbac1540
      x28: 0xfffffe0031377000 fp:  0xfffffe83e1697730  lr:  0x42f57e002f10a40c  sp:  0xfffffe83e16976b0
      pc:  0xfffffe002f10a414 cpsr: 0x60401208         esr: 0x96000006          far: 0x00000000000001ec

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0xff
OS release type: User
OS version: 23G93
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.6.0: Mon Jul 29 21:13:04 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.141.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: C58433CAF051B51A1E8941427B6C3CF3
Kernel UUID: 5CDB6E8A-1888-3A5C-92B3-86C864439A24
Boot session UUID: F3CF5714-B50C-4EF0-B593-474F835086A2
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.140.19
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000025608000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe002c60c000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000025610000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe002c614000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x0000000026b84000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe002db88000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1f505d0cf4e
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x66d38154 0x000f04f5
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x66d4df8c 0x0002fd39

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xfffffe180ee38000 - 0xfffffe380ee38000
  . VM    : 0xfffffe180ee38000 - 0xfffffe1cdbb04000
  . RO    : 0xfffffe1cdbb04000 - 0xfffffe1e7549c000
  . GEN0  : 0xfffffe1e7549c000 - 0xfffffe2342168000
  . GEN1  : 0xfffffe2342168000 - 0xfffffe280ee34000
  . GEN2  : 0xfffffe280ee34000 - 0xfffffe2cdbb00000
  . GEN3  : 0xfffffe2cdbb00000 - 0xfffffe31a87cc000
  . DATA  : 0xfffffe31a87cc000 - 0xfffffe380ee38000
  Metadata: 0xfffffe87e1c2c000 - 0xfffffe87e9c2c000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffe87e9c2c000 - 0xfffffe87ef96c000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xfffffe2342e94f90  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x000000016c00b0e0 }
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 8 PVH locks held: None
CORE 9 PVH locks held: None
CORE 10 PVH locks held: None
CORE 11 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0x000000019e4c9018, LR=0x000000019e922dc0, FP=0x000000016b301ac0
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe002dbbf0f4, LR=0xfffffe002dbbef8c, FP=0xfffffe83e00abbc0
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe002dc56c38, LR=0xfffffe002dc56c34, FP=0xfffffe83e090f5f0
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e0b2bef0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83df9dfef0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e105fef0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e16ffef0
CORE 8: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de4, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e122bef0
CORE 9: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e0fc3ef0
CORE 10: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e0ff3ef0
CORE 11: PC=0xfffffe002dc19de8, LR=0xfffffe002dc19de4, FP=0xfffffe83e157fef0
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 1 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xfffffe2cdcb365d0: 15708 pages, 23 threads: pid 152: WindowServer
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe2342e94f90, backtrace: 0xfffffe83e1696ad0, tid: 3092
          lr: 0xfffffe002dbdf48c  fp: 0xfffffe83e1696b60
          lr: 0xfffffe002dd2cabc  fp: 0xfffffe83e1696bd0
          lr: 0xfffffe002dd2ae88  fp: 0xfffffe83e1696ca0
          lr: 0xfffffe002db8f8cc  fp: 0xfffffe83e1696cb0
          lr: 0xfffffe002dbded80  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697060
          lr: 0xfffffe002e3e7248  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697080
          lr: 0xfffffe002e3f22dc  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697200
          lr: 0xfffffe002dd2c8d4  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697270
          lr: 0xfffffe002dd2b028  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697340
          lr: 0xfffffe002db8f8cc  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697350
          lr: 0xfffffe002f10a40c  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697730
          lr: 0xfffffe00302642f0  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697790
          lr: 0xfffffe0030267040  fp: 0xfffffe83e16977c0
          lr: 0xfffffe0030265cb0  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697850
          lr: 0xfffffe002e33e8b8  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697890
          lr: 0xfffffe002e33ebf8  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697a20
          lr: 0xfffffe002dcf7f70  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697b40
          lr: 0xfffffe002dbe6660  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697be0
          lr: 0xfffffe002dbbdd04  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697c30
          lr: 0xfffffe002dbd1908  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697c90
          lr: 0xfffffe002dbd1d28  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697d90
          lr: 0xfffffe002dd205c0  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697e40
          lr: 0xfffffe002dd2b2a4  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697f10
          lr: 0xfffffe002db8f8cc  fp: 0xfffffe83e1697f20
          lr: 0xfffffe002db8f894  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily(343.0)[EBFDA120-00DF-373B-8C7F-F72408E44AA7]@0xfffffe0030255aa0->0xfffffe0030298353
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[44EAEE3D-751F-3A0B-9AE3-99173AA796CC]@0xfffffe002e58b770->0xfffffe002e5df913
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver(265.0.0)[7476A877-30A4-32D3-9824-52889E332D7B]@0xfffffe002efee0f0->0xfffffe002f082f7f
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[C48CA6B5-18EA-38D0-9F38-444201E63F1F]@0xfffffe002f11c8b0->0xfffffe002f14d837
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily(1.0.0)[8A3718C7-CEB1-3243-BFB9-98B0065B6156]@0xfffffe002fd7ec10->0xfffffe002fe08a7f
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(352.50.1)[405AD4ED-22CC-339C-A58F-2F81660DE066]@0xfffffe00304660f0->0xfffffe00304937ff
         com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispT602X-DCP(140.0)[1142D102-E281-3EB2-A0D3-71271F58F23E]@0xfffffe002f0fd040->0xfffffe002f11c8af
            dependency: com.apple.AUC(1.0)[6D2A0558-0492-3F95-9C54-C453F374E336]@0xfffffe002e4e7290->0xfffffe002e4ecb33
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[44EAEE3D-751F-3A0B-9AE3-99173AA796CC]@0xfffffe002e58b770->0xfffffe002e5df913
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver(265.0.0)[7476A877-30A4-32D3-9824-52889E332D7B]@0xfffffe002efee0f0->0xfffffe002f082f7f
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager(1.0.1)[1F09A1D4-FE34-3326-A6FD-814DC34A0CAE]@0xfffffe002f308220->0xfffffe002f337567
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor(1)[D401BF31-9BE9-3AC1-9AED-4D1D0B3ADE9C]@0xfffffe003043c080->0xfffffe003043da33
            dependency: com.apple.driver.RTBuddy(1.0.0)[39C0F704-310A-3BE4-B4CC-FC96973AA0FC]@0xfffffe0030a03160->0xfffffe0030a47083
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily(1.0.0)[8A3718C7-CEB1-3243-BFB9-98B0065B6156]@0xfffffe002fd7ec10->0xfffffe002fe08a7f
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily(343.0.0)[EBFDA120-00DF-373B-8C7F-F72408E44AA7]@0xfffffe0030255aa0->0xfffffe0030298353
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP(343.0.0)[77A70D04-D737-3680-BADB-5980A256DCC9]@0xfffffe0030213ce0->0xfffffe0030255a93
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(352.50.1)[405AD4ED-22CC-339C-A58F-2F81660DE066]@0xfffffe00304660f0->0xfffffe00304937ff

last started kext at 182020142122: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    900.4.2 (addr 0xfffffe002cf21560, size 1630)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  380
com.apple.driver.AppleRAID  5.1.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtionFirmware   1.0.36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  495
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub    556
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   340.42
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.filesystems.nfs   1
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  2236.141.1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  650.140.2
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSleepPowerPolicy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleGL3590FirmwareUpdater 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSN012776Amp   740.41
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L84Audio  740.41
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCRetimer  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT6020CLPC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT6020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptControllerV2 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T602x   350.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   743
com.apple.driver.AppleT6021PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1
com.apple.driver.AppleProResHW  350.47.0
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    6.6.2
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispT602X-DCP   140.0
com.apple.AGXG14X   282.14
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  760.31.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8110DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  3.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT6020 1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUIO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   276.120.7
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   405
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  359
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    304
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   8.5.1
com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial   6.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   4.1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.serial 6.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtion    1.0.64
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  640.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   540.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUVDMDriver    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUVDM  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  340.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIPCI    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSyntheticGameController   11.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOHIDPowerSource   1
com.apple.driver.AppleCallbackPowerSource   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleI2CEthernetAquantia   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   740.41
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 740.41
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    340.16
com.apple.driver.IISAudioIsolatedStreamECProxy  340.16
com.apple.driver.ExclavesAudioKext  1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG14XRTBuddy    1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  282.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8112TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP-ASCWrap-v4  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 93.40.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T602x    840.3
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 340.8
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.81
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.13.0
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    598
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP-MXWrap-v1   1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT6000PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.3
com.apple.iokit.IOPortFamily    1.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1220.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1240.15
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1240.15
com.apple.driver.AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtionPortMonitor 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT602xPCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    556
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  245
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   495
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   495
com.apple.driver.AppleRSMChannel    1
com.apple.iokit.IORSMFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleLockdownMode  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleANELoadBalancer   7.453.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   7.453.0
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   352.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 340.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs    340.8
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  71.10.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  6.3.0
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.Compression   1.0
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    14.0



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 367146 (Uncompressed 915456) **


Please update your question with the output of this shell command: kmutil showloaded | grep -v com\.apple . You can skip the first two lines of output (headers). If there are no other lines, just say so.

@LincD. The only way I can run that command is after the computer restarts. Which is probably too late. Is there a way to cause that command to happen and the output to be saved whenever the computer crashes but before it reboots?

kmutil showloaded | grep -v com.apple
No variant specified, falling back to release
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID 

There are no other lines other than the first two.

I have exactly the same problem with an M2 MBP and a Samsung 8k TV connected via HDMI. It also started when I updated to Sonoma. I've tried multiple HDMI cables, nothing seems to make a difference. Unlike the OP, I've had it crash while I'm typing, so I doubt that "jiggler" or similar would help me. It averages around one crash per day, frequently while the system is inactive. A few times per month it happens while I'm actively using the system. Each time the right half of the display turns to active static and the left half turns a solid color, usually green. Then all black and reboot.

There are three possible causes of recurring kernel panics:

Defective or incompatible third-party kernel extensions.
An internal hardware fault, or a faulty peripheral.
A bug in the OS.

You've ruled out #1. You haven't quite ruled out #2, but since the problem only appeared when you upgraded to Sonoma, it seems unlikely. That leaves #3 as the most likely cause. Unfortunately, there's really nothing you can do about it. If you're lucky, the bug will be fixed in Sequoia. Otherwise you'll have to consider replacing that monitor, or at least changing the way you use it.
I should add that I'm assuming the panics only happen when the monitor is connected. If that assumption is wrong or untested, then some other peripheral (if any) may be involved.
Update: The OP reports that he stopped the panics by installing a freeware app called "Jiggler" that simulates user activity. I consider this a workaround rather than a solution, as it has obvious drawbacks. I'm not convinced that we really know the underlying cause of his problem. Clearly not everyone who connects a display to a Mac running Sonoma using HDMI has this problem. So if it's a bug, it takes something more than that to trigger it.

Correct. The panics only happen when the monitor is connected. It ruins my workflow because I do a lot of batch processing and exports as a photographer, so I have to sit there and play a computer game and wiggle the mouse or tap the command key every minute or so so that the window server doesn't go off into never, never land and crash the computer. It only happens when I'm not actively using the computer. So strange. You would think it would be the other way around with a window server, that normally would crash more while doing things with windows of apps on the computer.

Your answer gets at the heart of why I am asking the question here now out of desperation. I've given up hope on Apple's ever paying attention and noticing my multiple daily crash reports using their built-in Report option after the restart. But maybe if I post it here an Apple engineer will take notice so it can be fixed in Sequoia. Are there any Apple engineers on here that you know of that could be tagged?

I have no idea whether any Apple engineers read this site. If they do, they don't identify themselves. When I say you could change the way you use the monitor, I mean changing whatever settings you can, such as the resolution, or just disconnecting it when you're not at the machine. I wish I could be more helpful.

I'm forgetting one other obvious thing you could do: in the Lock Screen panel of System Settings, change the setting for "Turn display off when inactive" to "Never." You could also use a third-party utility such as "Amphetamine" in the App Store to prevent sleep. That might actually be a good solution, though it will waste energy.

I have it set to "Turn display off when inactive" to a one hour time right now. But sometimes the issue happens when I walk away for less than 5 minutes. And I have tried Amphetamine. It seems to work sometimes but then I still often come back to my computer crashed and waiting for me to login. The only time it doesn't happen is when I'm actually actively using the computer. And it's very unpredictable. Some days it has happened a dozen times. Other days it might only happen once. I'm usually good at guessing how to change my behavior not to trigger a bug, but this one really has me stumped.

To rule out #3 you could try factory resetting your Mac, which will fall back to a clean install of macOS Ventura? If the issue continues to persist when the screen is plugged in, it would suggest the GPU is faulty. Why? Well I’m not sure how Apple’s silicon GPUs work but previous Intel Macs with dedicated GPUs would always use that over the integrated GPUs when a screen is plugged in. So, if this only occurred when the screen is plugged in, it would indicate the dGPU was faulty. But again, I’m not sure how Apple’s GPUs work on M series Macs since it’s all integrated now?

It is possible that different GPU cores process different things on M-series Macs (I’m not sure how the cores work?) and that one core required to power the external screen has gone faulty? So, by resetting to macOS Ventura, it will rule out if it’s a OS bug, because it could very well be pure coincidence that the GPU went faulty just as you installed Sonoma (you’d have to be very unlucky but not impossible)

Also check which resolutions and refresh rates your Mac Studio M2 Max can support https://support.apple.com/en-au/101910 note it says you can’t use the front 2 USB-C ports for external displays on Mac Studio models with M2 Max models. Although they will work with Mac Studio models with M2 Ultra though. Another thing to consider is try connecting the external display to another port, because the I/O port might be faulty

If you have, or can borrow, another HDMI cable, try it.

I found a couple of apps that seem to simulate user activity. Maybe one of them would help you as an interim solution. link link

I'll try the jiggler one and set it to only do it after a while. The only issue of course, is that I want my computer screen to be able to rest while I'm doing things like batch processing photos and running errands away from my computer. I'll try powering off the screen maybe but leaving the HDMI 2.1 cable plugged in, all while running the Jiggler app.

So far no crashes and restarts after installing the jiggler. The main issue is my computer never logs out now. I don't mind too much, but obviously this would be a show stopper for many users. I just power off the Samsung TV/monitor now to save energy instead of using a screen saver, then turn it on again when I go back to my computer. Apple still needs to fix this horrific and embarrassing bug, though. I haven't seen an issue like this since doing development with the X.org window system long ago. A finished OS like macOS should never crash just because a type of monitor is plugged into HDMI.

Apparently some samsung displays will cause your mac to kernel panic when you wake your mac from sleep, which suggests perhaps it's more of a Samsung firmware issue? However others suggest it has something to do with having external displays but also some external drives plugged in at the same time? Do you use any external drives?

Update: my computer just crashed again, this time with a different message. watchdog timeout, no checkins in 181 seconds, shutdown in progress, panic, etc. The panicked task is pid 0, kernel_task. I wonder if a week or so with no sleep is too much for the operating system to handle. Unlike Windows, Unix should be able to run forever, and macOS is based on that, but I wonder if some type of leak is present that made it crash after too long without sleep. I was good for about 6 days without crashes until now. And this time it started to lock up and not respond while I was using the computer.
